# Why I cannot cast oracle BLOB from native java Blob

Tags: java, oracle, blob, classcastexception

I am reading file from ResultSet and it's required to save file into Oracle Database.

```
...
ResultSet rs = ...
java.sql.Blob myfile = rs.getBlob("field")
java.io.OutputStream os = ((oracle.sql.BLOB) myfile).getBinaryOutputStream();
```

I get get this error message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Any one have solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. I'd like to share with those who has this problem.

The code to get outputstream from oracle blob is:

```
java.io.OutputStream os = ((oracle.sql.BLOB) myBlob).setBinaryStream(1L);
```

setBinaryStream() is actually returning java.io.OutputStream object

Comment: @ericbn Please do not edit the question in a way that changes its meaning/intent. Instead, add a comment indicating the way in which you think it should be changed.

Answer (score 3):

`java.sql.Blob` [is an interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html). Presumably the implementation returned in your `ResultSet` is a different implementation to `oracle.sql.BLOB`?

What does `myfile.getClass()` return?

Comment: I guess you are right. these two Blog are not compatible. I now use weblogic.jdbc.common.OracleBlob, it works fine. Although it is deprecated. But will keep it until we upgrade to Java 5 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to not have an oracle.sql.BLOB there (if you did, it should work, BLOB implements Blob). What does the ClassCastException say it is?

What version of Oracle and what version of the JDBC driver are you using?

*getBinaryOutputStream* is deprecated anyway, you should use *setBinaryStream* in the JDBC (3.0) interface, which probably removes the need to go to Oracle's internal class at all.

Comment: You had a good tip on using "setBinaryStream" defined in JDBC 3.0.

Unfortunately my application still using 1.4. Again will wait until we upgrade :)