# Cannot Convert from SerialBlob to BLOB

Tags: java, blob

I am converting a document to byte array, After that, Converting that byte array to oracle BLOB object. But when I am converting I am getting error.

code -

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
BLOB blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(pdfBytes);
```

Error -

```
 cannot convert from `SerialBlob` to BLOB
```

Comment: using JDBC or Hibernate

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing Oracle and Java 7 JDBC types here. `BLOB` is something which Oracle invented and which doesn't fit really well into the rest of the JDBC design which is one reason why you can't cast the two.

Either use `java.sql.Blob` or only use Oracle's types (i.e. replace `SerialBlob` with `oracle.sql.BLOB` plus the necessary streams).

Related:

- [Using Large Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html) - Oracle JDBC Tutorial
- [Why I cannot cast oracle BLOB from native java Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379594/why-i-cannot-cast-oracle-blob-from-native-java-blob)
- [Overcomplicated oracle jdbc BLOB handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862355/overcomplicated-oracle-jdbc-blob-handling)